# Is this an example of run-on sentence?

Tags: run-on-sentence

> To understand mental strength, you have to learn how your thoughts, behaviours, and feelings are all intertwined, often working together to create a dangerous downward spiral as in the preceding example.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? Isn't this part of the sentence, "often working together to create a dangerous downward spiral as in the preceding example", make it run-on sentence?

Also, what is the rule behind using phrases like this "as in the preceding example?"

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: It's not a run-on sentence. But I'd not give it many marks for style.